# python error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I need to count how many lines in the returned value in variable"data",but it doesn't accept the variable as how it is, here is what i did and the error:

```
sum_lines =0
data=subprocess.call(["nova list"],shell=True)
for line in data:
        print line
       sum_lines += 1
print sum_lines
```

The error

```
  File "./code.py", line 9, in <module>
    for line in data:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

THE SOLUTION: i had to use check_output

```
data=subprocess.check_output("nova show "+new+"."+projid_new, shell=True)
for line in data.splitlines():
        sum_lines +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

According to docs, [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) returns error code.

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then
>   return the returncode attribute.

Trying to iterate over return code (which is an integer) results in `'int' object is not iterable` exception.

To get standard output, you need to use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

Since output is already one huge string and does not support lazy file-like protocol, to access separate lines you need to split your string, e.g. by using [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries.
>   This method uses the universal newlines approach to splitting lines.
>   Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends is
>   given and true.

So your code would look like:

```
sum_lines = 0
data = subprocess.call(["nova list"], shell=True)
for line in data.splitlines():
    print line
    sum_lines += 1
print sum_lines
```

To simply count number of lines, `len(data.splitlines())` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.call() check it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

It returned an integer not iterable object, therefore you cannot iterate the return value.

Comment: That is what i did and worked for me
data=subprocess.check_output("nova show "+new+"."+projid_new, shell=True)
for line in data.splitlines():
        sum_lines +=1